# python for loop MIME sendmail sends out the same content

Tags: python

The code I have below has a list containing different types of html formatted messages.  This code is suppose to send one email for each element in the list.  the problem is, it isn't.  The subject changes, but the content is the same for all the emails sent.

```
for eachrecord in fformatErrMessage:
    hostNameinfo = eachrecord.split()[0].replace("Hostname=[[u'","").replace("']]","").replace(",","")
    hostNameIP = eachrecord.split()[1].replace("IP=[","").replace("]","").replace(",","")
    hostGroups = eachrecord.split()[2].replace("HostGroups=[","").replace("]","")
    storageinfo = eachrecord.split()[4].replace("Disk=[","").replace("]","").replace(",","")
    currentValue = str(eachrecord.split()[8].replace(",","").replace("C.V","Current.Pct.Free"))
    #previousValue = str(eachrecord.split()[9].replace(",",""))
    #print(currentValue,previousValue)
    lastHostNchar = hostNameinfo[-1]
    if lastHostNchar == "w" or lastHostNchar == "W":
        hostOS = "(os:Windows)"
    elif lastHostNchar == "l" or lastHostNchar == "L":
        hostOS = "(os:Linux)"
    else:
        hostOS = "(os:N/A)"
    subjectMsg = "Predictive Disk Space SRQ - [ {hostNameinfo} ] - {hostOS}".format(**locals())
    #subjectBody = "Drive [ {storageinfo} ] on Host [ {hostNameinfo}, {hostNameIP} ] needs Urgent Attention - Current.Pct.Free=[{currentValue}%] - Previous.Pct.Free=[{previousValue}%] - Associated HostGroups [ {hostGroups} ]".format(**locals())
    ####
    msg['Subject'] = subjectMsg
    #text = subjectBody
    text = "nothing"
    ####
    html = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <p> </p>
           <p>Drive [ {storageinfo} ] on Host [ {hostNameinfo}, {hostNameIP} ] needs Urgent Attention:</p>
           <ul>
           <li> {currentValue}% </li>
           <li> Associated HostGroups [ {hostGroups} ]</li>
           <li> Possible Resolution Steps -</li>
               <ol>
                   <li> Clear/Free up disk space</li>
                   <li> Add more storage to the drive</li>
               </ol>
           <ul>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
    """.format(**locals())
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Can anyone spot any obvious errors?  I've been trying to fix this on my own for a couple of hours now and I dont know what else to try.

I confirmed the content of the `html` variable is different by adding the following right after the html variable definition.

```
print(html)
continue
```

I dont know what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, you use same instance of `msg` in each iteration without any "clean" action. That's where problem could appear. Try to create new instance of `msg` for each sending action.

```
for eachrecord in fformatErrMessage:
    # Preparing all variables #
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = subjectMsg
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Comment: This seems to work.  But now it sends the message as an attachment instead of in the body of the email.  What could be wrong?